# Adding DIV dynamically to the BODY using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I try to add a DIV to the body, but I obtained a blank page.
This is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cFens/1/).

In the same example I uncommented the HTML because is working fine.

Code :

```
$("body").append('<div data-role="page"><div data-role="content">HOME</div></div>');
$("body").collapsibleset();
```

Comment: If you inspect the HTML using FireBug or Chrome's debugger, you can see that the div is being added, it's just not showing up in the jsFiddle window.

Comment: I understand, but why ? I have the same problem in my browser..

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because `data-role= "page"` has a `display` of `none`.
[image]

I don't know where this css if coming from, but if you disable it as I did, "Home" shows up

**EDIT**
This css is coming from jquery mobile.  You could either manually set the css for `data-role="page"` to `display:block;` in your stylesheet to override jquery, or you don't even have to assign it in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I added an ID to the page and invoked the `show()` mothod of jquery. It worked

```
$("body").html('<div data-role="page" id="myPage"><div data-role="content"><p>HOME</p> </div></div>');
$("#myPage").show();
```

Please check out the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cFens/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck `jQuery Mobile 1.1.1` and check something else like `jQuery UI 1.8.18` in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFens/1/)